# What's the difference between VARCHAR(255) and TINYTEXT string types in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types

What's the difference between VARCHAR(255) and TINYTEXT string types in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)?

Each of them allows to store strings with a maximum length of 255 characters. Storage requirements are also the same. When should I prefer one over another?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You cannot assign a `DEFAULT` value to a `TINYTEXT` and you cannot create an unprefixed index on the latter.

Internally, additional objects are allocated in memory to handle `TEXT` (incl. `TINYTEXT`) columns which can cause memory fragmentation on the large recordsets.

Note that this only concerns the column's internal representation in the recordsets, not how they are stored on the disk.

Comment: What about, when mysql needs to temporary table, if a blob or text (inc. tinytext) it uses the disk instead of memory to create the temporary table

Comment: Which one is cheaper (time & CPU cycles) to search?

Answer (score 11):

Using `VARCHAR` you can set the column to `NULL` or `NOT NULL` and you can set `DEFAULT` value, but not with `TEXT`. Use `VARCHAR` if you need one or both feature, `NULL` and `DEFAULT`.

Comment: TINYTEXT column can also be NULL.

Comment: But not default

Answer (score -2):

in varchar you have to set the  length of a character whereas in tanytext there is nothing like this it saves the memory of data base for ex:

for address you have to define the varchar(50) than your address may be 50 charecter or less the worse condition is your character more than the 50 character  this is the limitation of varchar if character is less than 50 than it occupy the 50 character memory in this case memory is increases

so use tanytext it define the character length depend upon the size of character so memory is saved

Comment: This is wrong. A varchar only uses as much memory as the length of what is currently stored (in contrast to char). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Hi viblo, in varchar we pre define the length of string it takes memory upto predefined limit. this is not in case of tanytext.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. The MySQL docs says that a varchar requires "L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes" where L is the actual length of the text being stored, not what you defined the varchar to have as max length.

Comment: @nilesh - `TINYTEXT` has an _implicit_ max of 255 _bytes_ (or maybe 256).

Comment: @viblo is right. Check out the mysql documentation and you will see.

Comment: @viblo nilesh is right, at least for older version. Just look at source code. Varchar pads zeroes upto its declared length in memory. Blob and Text are more efficient in this regard. There is a difference between memory structures and disc file structures. Varchar is stored efficiently in file only, not in memory.