# Is there any reason to ever use TINYTEXT?

Tags: mysql, database, varchar, sqldatatypes, tinytext

As far as I can tell, `VARCHAR(255)` does everything `TINYTEXT` can do. `VARCHAR` has the same storage size, it's part of the ISO standard, it allows default values other than null. I can't see any reason to ever use `TINYTEXT`. But it exists, so maybe there's a reason.

Is there any situation where `TINYTEXT` would be the preferred data type for size, speed, or other considerations?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288628/whats-the-difference-between-varchar255-and-tinytext-string-types-in-mysql ?

Comment: @Varon I disagree. None of the answers to that question give a definitive yes or no as to whether or not there is ever a good situation to use TINYTEXT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only situation I can think of where `TINYTEXT` might be helpful is if you have **really** large rows. The contents of `VARCHAR` columns counts against the maximum row size of 65,535 bytes, but `TEXT` and `BLOB` data does not; a `TINYTEXT` column only adds 1 byte to the row size.

Actually, for InnoDB tables, things are somewhat more complicated. InnoDB storage is described in the following pages:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-compression-internals.html

To summarize, the data stored in the part of the table subject to the above limit for `TINYTEXT` consists of a 1-byte length field and a 20-byte pointer to the external data, so a `TINYTEXT` adds 21 bytes to the row length. However, when an external value is less than 40 bytes, the data is stored inline in the row. So for a `TINYTEXT` less than 40 bytes, the storage is similar to `VARCHAR(255)`, and it's all counted against the row length limit.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the max row size, and is it engine-specific?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html. The maximum for any engine is 65,535, but some engines may have smaller limits.

Comment: In InnoDB, it takes 20 bytes per column to point to the off-record storage for big `VARCHARs` and `TEXT`.

Comment: @RickJames I think you mean `BLOB` and `TEXT`. Do you have a reference for that 20 byte figure, I can't find it in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-compression-internals.html "When a table is created with a DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format, long column values are stored fully off-page, and the clustered index record contains only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page. By comparison, the COMPACT row format stores up to the first 768 bytes of variable-length columns values in the clustered index record along with a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page. "

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to include this detail.

Comment: There are 4 `ROW_FORMATs`; what you added applies to some of them.  For now, I suggest it is "good enough" for this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

`TINYTEXT` is essentially useless.  It probably exists for consistency (4 sizes of `TEXT` and `BLOB`).  `TINYTEXT` existed in MySQL long before `VARCHAR` could have more than 255 characters and before a character could be more than one byte.

`TINYTEXT` actually has disadvantages over `VARCHAR`.  A complex `SELECT` may need to create a tmp table (eg, for `ORDER BY`); the first preference is to use `MEMORY`.  The fallback is the less efficient `MyISAM`.  Any size `TEXT` and `BLOB` forces going straight to `MyISAM`.

A *difference* is that the number in `VARCHAR` is *characters*; the `TEXT` sizes are measured in *bytes*.  A utf8 *character* can occupy up to 3 *bytes*.

Bottom line:  Don't use `TINYTEXT`.  (Or `TINYBLOB`, which can be replaced by `VARBINARY(...)`.)

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I'm talking about tinyTEXT not tinyINT.  In Innodb, every column has the same overhead (1- or 2-bytes, depending on the declared size of the widest column in the table).  `LONGTEXT` (etc) have 20(?) bytes of overhead to point to the off-record storage (etc).  There are _some_ clues in the manual where it discusses "row formats".

Comment: Correction: 1 byte lengths if the total size for the row is under 128 bytes.